# Pygame how to handle states

Tags: python, pygame, state

I recently finished a connect-four type game in python with pygame. After either player has won, it shows a menu asking if you want to play again or quit, with a button for each option. The program knows whether to run the game or show the menu based on a variable in the `Game` class, which contains the game's state. The problem is that I then have to have an `if` - `elif` clause at several points in the program to see what to do. For example, in the `Game.draw` method, it either draws the game board and pieces or the menu, the `Game.on_click` method sends the event either to the game board or to the buttons in the menu, etc. So my question is, is there a way to keep track of the game state without needing `if` - `elif` clauses scattered throughout the program?

game.py:

```
import pygame

from board import Board
from player import Player
from button import Button
from constants import (
    BLACK,
    RED,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    WHITE,
    SQUARE_SIZE,
    ROWS,
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT
)


class Game:
    PLAYING = 0
    HAS_WON = 1

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win
        # self.running = True
        self.state = self.PLAYING
        self.running = True
        self.board = Board()

        self.players = [Player(RED, self.board), Player(YELLOW, self.board)]
        self.player_turn_counter = 0

        pygame.font.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        self.text = ""

        play_again_xpos = WIDTH // 5
        play_again_ypos = (HEIGHT // 5) * 4
        play_again_button = Button("Play Again",
                                   GREEN,
                                   self.play_again,
                                   xpos=play_again_xpos,
                                   ypos=play_again_ypos,
                                   show_border=True,
                                   border_color=(255, 255, 255))

        quit_xpos = (WIDTH // 5) * 4
        quit_ypos = (HEIGHT // 5) * 4
        quit_button = Button("Quit",
                             RED,
                             self.quit,
                             xpos=quit_xpos,
                             ypos=quit_ypos,
                             show_border=True,
                             border_color=(255, 255, 255))

        self.buttons = [play_again_button, quit_button]

    def play_again(self):
        self.__init__(self.win)
        self.run()

    def quit(self):
        self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        self.win.fill(BLACK)
        self.board.draw(self.win)
        if self.state == self.HAS_WON:
            # self.win.fill(WHITE)
            text = self.font.render(self.text, True, WHITE)

            text_rect = text.get_rect()
            text_rect.centerx = WIDTH // 2
            text_rect.centery = ((SQUARE_SIZE * ROWS) // 3) - SQUARE_SIZE // 2

            self.win.blit(text, text_rect)

            for button in self.buttons:
                button.draw(self.win)
            # self.play_again_button.draw(self.win)
            # self.quit_button.draw(self.win)

        pygame.display.update()

    def is_full(self, column):
        board = self.board.get_board()
        # pieces = []

        # for row in board:
        #     pieces.append(row[column])

        # return all(pieces)
        return all([row[column] for row in board])

    def on_win(self, color):
        self.state = self.HAS_WON
        colors = {(255, 255, 0): "Yellow", (255, 0, 0): "Red"}
        self.text = f"{colors[color]} has won!"
        # print(f"{colors[color]} has won!")

    def on_click(self):
        if self.state == self.PLAYING:
            column = self.board.get_column()
            if not self.is_full(column):
                self.player_turn_counter += 1
                self.player_turn_counter = self.player_turn_counter % 2
            self.players[self.player_turn_counter].on_click()
            has_won, color = self.board.check_for_win()
            if has_won:
                self.on_win(color)
        elif self.state == self.HAS_WON:
            for button in self.buttons:
                button.on_click()

    def run(self):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        while self.running:
            clock.tick(60)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.on_click()

            self.draw()
```

Heres the github repo for the whole program:
https://github.com/pianocomposer321/ConnectFour.git

Comment: I would separate the game into 2 main functions - menu and game. Each function has a draw loop (`while running:...`). In the menu function, the loop ends when the user clicks 'Play' and the game function ends when a player wins\loses. Put the main functions in a loop so the menu returns after the game ends. The program ends when the user chooses 'Quit' in the menu.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going a different route than your answer if I remember correctly, but I'll go ahead and accept your answer for future reference in case anyone else stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two classes with the same interface, one for each state. The classes contain the implementation that relates to a state of the game:

```py
class Playing:
    def __init__(self, game)
        self.game = game

    def draw(self):
        # [...]

    def on_click(self):
        # [...]
```

```py
class HasWon:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

    def draw(self):
        # [...]

    def on_click(self):
        # [...]
```

The `Game` class uses the classes that implement the states of the game. An additional attribute (`self.current`) refers to the the current *state* class. An additional method (`set_state`) switch the state variable and sets `self.current` dependent on the state. This is the only point in the program where you need the `if` - `elif` clause.In the other methods, you can delegate to the implementation method of the game state implementation (e.g. `self.current.draw()`, `self.current.on_click()`):

```py
class Game:
    PLAYING = 0
    HAS_WON = 1

    def __init__(self, win):
        # [...]

        self.playing = Playing(self)
        self.haswon = HasWon(self)
        self.set_state(self.PLAYING)
        
    def set_state(new_state):
        self.state = self.PLAYING
        if self.state == self.PLAYING:
            self.current = self.playing
        elif self.state == self.HAS_WON:
            self.current = self.haswon

    def draw(self):
        self.win.fill(BLACK)
        self.board.draw(self.win)
        
        self.current.draw()

        pygame.display.update()

    def on_win(self, color):
        self.set_state(self.HAS_WON)
        # [...]
        

    def on_click(self):
        self.current.on_click()
```